# In WPF code-behind, how do I set the background color for each individual ListBoxItem where the color is based on the item itself?

Tags: wpf, colors, background, code-behind, listboxitem

My end goal is to have a `ListBox` show me a list of colors, where the value of the background color is the color itself. Eventually, this `ListBox` will load a previously saved collection of colors, but for now I'm just trying to get it to work with dummy data - a dictionary I filled up using the colors from `System.Windows.Media.Colors` (`<string, Color>`, where `string` is the friendly name and `Color` is a custom class that only contains the `Red`, `Green`, `Blue`, and `Hex` values for the color). It's set up this way because the user-stored colors will eventually just have a name (the key), and RGB/Hex values.

I have no problem getting the names of the colors to show up in the `ListBox` by settings its `ItemsSource` to `App.SavedColors.Keys` (where `SavedColors` is the previously mentioned dictionary). And I found some answers that could explain how to do it based off of a property if you knew what colors you wanted (i.e. "green" if "severity" or something was equal to 1), but nothing for binding the color as well.

Using a solution I found while trying to research this, I was able to figure out how to *almost* make it work. But it seems like this code just colors the backgrounds of *all* the items, according to the color of the *last* item, so I imagine this just changes the overall background color every time a new row is created. How do I keep each iteration from overwriting the previous background?

The closest code I've been able to use so far:

```
//Bind the saved colors.
ListBox_SavedColors.ItemsSource = App.SavedColors.Keys;

//Color the backgrounds.
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox_SavedColors.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //Create the blank style.
    Style styleBackground = new System.Windows.Style();
    styleBackground.TargetType = typeof(ListBoxItem);

    //Get the color and store it in a brush.
    Color color = App.SavedColors[ListBox_SavedColors.Items[i].ToString()];
    SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
    backgroundBrush.Color = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(color.Red, color.Green, color.Blue);

    //Create a background setter and add the brush to it.
    styleBackground.Setters.Add(new Setter
    {
        Property = ListBoxItem.BackgroundProperty,
        Value = backgroundBrush
    });

    ListBox_SavedColors.ItemContainerStyle = styleBackground;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a code-behind solution? It's much easier in XAML.

Comment: It definitely doesn't have to be. I'm just very new to WPF/XAML, so I'm far more comfortable/confident with the C# code-behind. I'm definitely willing to learn the XAML for it if you knew where to point me. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you assign the same property ItemsContainerStyle that impacts all of the ListBoxItems. So all of the items will have the color of the last one.

Your code should directly assign the Background of the items.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox_SavedColors.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //Get the color and store it in a brush.
    Color color = App.SavedColors[ListBox_SavedColors.Items[i].ToString()];
    SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(color);

    ListBoxItem item = ListBox_SavedColors.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i) as ListBoxItem;
    item.Background = backgroundBrush;
}
```

But as Peter Hansen it is better to use a XAML to solve this problem. For exemple you can write a converter that will convert the data in the ListBoxItem into a SolidColorBrush. Then you can bind the background of an item to its content.

```
public class ListBoxItemColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(App.SavedColors[value.ToString()]);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML will look like this:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyList">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <local:ListBoxItemColorConverter x:Key="ListBoxItemColorConverter"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ListBoxItemColorConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I am definitely interested in this converter method. Whatever is simpler is honestly what I'm going for. That being said, thank you for finding the error in my code! Classic instance of over-complicating things...

Comment: After trying this code, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` for `item`. It doesn't seem like the `ItemContainerGenerator` is correctly grabbing the `ListBoxItem` given the index.

Comment: Really strange. Are you using a ListBox? Did you use Virtualization? I've added Convertor Method to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a ListBox. Unless it's default, I didn't use Virtualization (new to WPF/XAML, so I don't even know what that means without looking it up). As for the Converter method, where should I be storing these things? I put the code-behind in the App.xaml.cs file, but when I tried to access it in the XAML for the Listbox, `local:ListBoxItemColorConverter` isn't resolving for me. I think there are more steps to this that a beginner like me might be missing.

EDIT: I looked up the error I was getting and learned how to add the local namespace.

Comment: You put the c# code in a separate file. It is a standalone class. Then you declare in your xaml a xmlns:local=... you will have autocompletion and you need to choose the namespace of your converter.

Comment: Thanks.. In debugging, I can see that the converter is being called, and it is returning the `System.Windows.Media.Color`. But when the ListBox actually renders, all of the items still have a white background. Is there another basic step I might have missed? No more errors, just still not seeing the functionality.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. The background property is expecting a `Brush`, not a `Color`. I created a new brush in the converter and set the color to the color being retrieved, then returned the brush. It's working now. Thank you very much! :D