# How to set custom background to ListView item color behind code?

Tags: c#

I've a list View that look like this:

```
<ListView Name="Playing" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = MatchDate}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Header="Minute" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = MatchMinute}"/>
     </GridView>
 </ListView.View>
```

this list view source is an `ObservableCollection`. What I'm trying to do is set a custom background color to a specific item in the `ListView`.

For this I made a method `SetNotification()` that have this code:

```
Playing.SelectedItems.Add(item);
```

where `item` is the current item available in the `ObservableCollection`. Now this isn't the wanted result 'cause this set the select propert to the item, I need to set a custom background to this item. Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How i change ListView Item Background Color according to listview item HarfNotu value in wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126393/how-i-change-listview-item-background-color-according-to-listview-item-harfnotu)

Comment: the question that you linked use a xaml solution , I need a code behind

Comment: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23302135/1997232), but why? How exactly you determine that custom color? Setting item property (in code behind of View or ViewModel) is preferable than obtaining `ListViewItem` and operating its properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var x = lview.ItemContainerStyle.Setters;
        Setter s = new Setter();
        s.Property = BackgroundProperty;
        s.Value = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 0, 0));
        x.Add(s);
```

**Caution:** It will set the same color for all the ListView Items.

Comment: I've no BackgroundProperty maybe I should using some reference?

Comment: @AgainMe its part of the `Control` class, it should be there.